# IP forwarding Ubuntu

Tags: networking, iptables, ip

For my work we have a testing space with a Ubuntu server which is also a router.
Yesterday we placed a new in the rack and our meaning was to make it a webserver which is accessible from the internet. The Ubuntu server/router was only a router first, which redirects the traffic from inside to the outside and it was a DHCP server.

To make the router route to the Internet we used `iptables` for NAT:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [323:23056]
:INPUT ACCEPT [59:6795]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [31:2677]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth5 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [278:36336]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [18603:9408689]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [105:12060]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Now we want to redirect some traffic to the webserver, but we have a few public IP addresses. We want to route all traffic to IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.14 to the internal IP address 10.10.10.10.

I tried to apply the following rules in the `iptables`:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d xxx.xxx.xxx.14 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10 -j SNAT --to-source xxx.xxx.xxx.14
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Since my Ubuntu/Linux skills are very low, I don't exactly what I am doing wrong. Can somebody help me with my problem?

The meaning is that all traffic to IP xxx.xxx.xxx.14 is being redirected to 10.10.10.10. All the other traffic doesn't need to be touched and can be redirected as normal NAT traffic to `eth5`.

`eth2` is the outside ethernet port. `eth5` is the inside ethernet port.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if ip forwarding is enabled, and if not then enable it.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

```
$ sudo su
# echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# exit
exit
$
```

EDIT: O.K. so ip_forward is enabled.

then delete the line that does MASQUERADE to eth5.
make sure the your specific POSTROUTING command is in the rule set before the generic one. I am saying that this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10 -j SNAT --to-source xxx.xxx.xxx.14
```

might need to be this:

```
iptables -t nat -I 1 POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10 -j SNAT --to-source xxx.xxx.xxx.14
```

(or similar, I did not check the syntax) or if you have the entire master rule set, put it before the other one.

Notes:
With default policy rules of ACCEPT, you do not need your conditional ACCEPTs.

Comment: ip forwarding is enabled, so that shouldn't be the problem.
About the same PREROUTING rule, my bad, copy/paste mistake.
It is:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d xxx.xxx.xxx.14 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.10
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10 -j SNAT --to-source xxx.xxx.xxx.14